# Powershell Query users

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, azure-powershell

I have an issue with some query parts dues to some failures in the system so basically, I have to search all AD users, and check which user is member of a specific group. 
Using the Get-ADgroupMember does not return anything as I can not query in the specific group, I have to work around it such as checking users and checking if they are members of the group and if so, listing them into a csv/txt file.

Any ideas on how to tackle this one?

Comment: You might wanna edit your question to include just what you have tried and details on how it failed. But, `Get-ADUser -Identity <user> -Properties memberOf` (or -Filter * if that's what you want) should get your group membership info as well.

Comment: So you are working on the on-promise AD?

Comment: Get-ADUser -Filter * | Properties MemberOf  "Administrators"  | Export-csv . . . something like this I guess?

Comment: @JoyWang yes. it is necessary and I have to clean up 25k users and re-organise.

Comment: Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties MemberOf "Users" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DisplayName | Export-csv -path "C:\Users\GroupmembersAdministrare.csv" -NoTypeInformation 

This is what I have and yet I still have some errors, maybe the part with the Identity ? I want to search the entire AD not a specific user. 

Get-ADUser : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Users'

Comment: The property memberOf is not a filter. You run `Get-ADUser -Filter *` to get all the user objects. Adding `-Property memberOf` means that for all the returned user objects you want to include the information from the `memberOf` property. Using the details you get from memberOf you should then be able to include or exclude specific group memberships... In theory, and this is why I asked for details on what you've tried and how that failed since it very well might matter. For instance looking for O365 group members by querying on prem AD or vice versa might not get you the output. Sys failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $users= Get-ADUser -Filter {name -like "*" } -Properties memberof $Groups= Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like "*" } -Properties memberof
>    Select-Object -ExpandProperty memberof | where memberof -EQ "Users" Foreach( $user in $users)  {
>
> $grups= $user | Select-Object -ExpandProperty memberof
>
> If( $grups -contains "Users,OU=txx,OU=Admin,DC=COM,DC=Digital") 
>       { 
>       Add-ADGroupMember "Users" -Members $user.Samaccountname
>       } } Foreach( $grup in $groups ) {
>
> ```
> $member = $grup | Select-Object -ExpandProperty memberof
>
> If( $member -contains "Users,OU=txx,OU=Admin,DC=COM,DC=Digital") {
>
>     Add-ADGroupMember "Users" -Members $grup.Name
>
> }
>     }
> ```

Found the solution.